# Pass Variables from Button to Form on Next Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to pass variables from a button to an input form on another page.

For example,

The user clicks a button with the package they want, the button loads the next page and fill out the form with the package information they have selected. What is the best way to go about this? I am designing the website using Joomla.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: what have you tried so far, showing some code that you have will make it better for people trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to use localStorage to get this done.

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', value);
```

then get it on other page like this:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
```

then set the text field with `retrievedObject` .

see this post to get better idea:[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)